# Using python + requests to download multiple zip files from links

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-re

I am trying to download zipped files from the US census bureau (https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2019/PLACE/). The code I have so far appeared to work, but all of the files downloaded are empty. Can someone help fill in what i'm missing? [image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re

DOMAIN = "https://www2.census.gov/"
URL = "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2019/PLACE/"


def get_soup(URL):
    return bs(requests.get(URL).text, 'html.parser')

for link in get_soup(URL).findAll("a", attrs={'href': re.compile(".zip")}):
    file_link = link.get('href')
    print(file_link)

with open(link.text, 'wb') as file:
    response = requests.get(DOMAIN + file_link)
    file.write(response.content)
```

Comment: if you open one of the downloaded files in an editor, what does it contain? It'll probably be a "scraping not allowed" or similar message.

Comment: @barny When I try opening with 7zip, and get the error message "Can not open file 'C://xx/xx/tl_2019_55_place.zip' as an archive"

Comment: yes it isn't an archive - open it in an editor like notepad or notepad++ - or modify your code to print what it receives?

Comment: @barny Oh I see --- Here is the first line of what opens... <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head><!--Each page must contain this info, per OMB, update info as neccessary--><meta http-

Comment: Try printing out the url you're going to get, make sure it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the wrong links.

After looking at the website I can see that the download links have the following URL: "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2019/PLACE/[file_link]",

So currently your DOMAIN variable is wrong it should instead be using your URL variable.

Currently, the "with open" also isn't indented to work with all the links in the for-loop so only the last link is downloaded in the current state your code.

Comment: Ah!! That's right. I changed that portion of the code to use the URL variable instead of the DOMAIN variable and everything is downloading fully. Thanks a bunch!